How to Diagnose and Fix python .\app.py not working
I activated my virtual environment in vs code. In the PowerShell where my environment was activated, I installed Flask successfully. Then I ran this code in my file main.py:
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

But when I try to run the command python .\main.py in the PowerShell where my environment is activated, it displays:
(venv) PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\myprj> 

It doesn't give me the link to my web.

Your issue is in your main code. Specifically:
if __name__ == "__main":

This isn't the proper name. Instead, this should be "__main__". So that line should read:
#                     ⬇️
if __name__ == "__main__":

Otherwise your program will not have any output - because the name will actually be __main__.
Full code:
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

Also see: What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?

Thanks but it doesn't work. It still gives the same result. I'll edit my question as well. BTW anymore suggestions.
